# How to pass different props to different screen in the Navigator?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to create a News app with different categories filter. In order to do so, I have to pass props to different screens in my Navigator so that the component can use the props for the fetch api.
For example:

```
export default createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions:{
            tabBarLabel: "Home",
        },
        props: {id: 1}
    },
    BeautyScreen: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions:{
            tabBarLabel: "Beauty tips",
        },
        props: {id: 2}
    },
    BusinessScreen: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions:{
            tabBarLabel: "Business related",
        },
        props: {id: 3}
    },
    CarsScreen: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions:{
            tabBarLabel: "Cars related",
        },
        props: {id: 4}
    },
)}
```

As you can see, i can use the same `HomeScreen` component with different props, i can pass in the api for example: `fetch("https://some-api.com/?category=" + navigations.props.id)`.

this is what i have right now, i have to create different component for different screens for what is basically the same component with different api.

```
export default createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions:{
            tabBarLabel: "Home",
        }
    },
    BeautyScreen: {
        screen: BeautyScreen,
        navigationOptions:{
            tabBarLabel: "Beauty tips",
        }
    },
    BusinessScreen: {
        screen: BusinessScreen,
        navigationOptions:{
            tabBarLabel: "Business related",
        }
    },
    CarsScreen: {
        screen: CarsScreen,
        navigationOptions:{
            tabBarLabel: "Cars related",
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found out that react navigation v3 support this

```
BeautyScreen: {
    screen: OtherCategoriesScreens,
    navigationOptions:{
        tabBarLabel: "Beauty",
    },
    params: {
        categories: [
            {
                name: "Fashion",
                id: 144,
            },
            {
                name: "Make up",
                id: 143,
            },
        ]
    }
},
```

And then you can use `this.props.navigation.getParam('categories')` in the screen component to get the Param.